# Custom SeekBar in Kotlin

Tags: android, seekbar, android-seekbar, seekbar-thumb, rangeseekbar

I want to create a **Custom Seekbar** like this. Please give some idea to create this type of **seek bar** in **Kotlin**

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScHBK.png